# Trouble understanding this sentence

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Michael Lewis wrote this in *Liar's Poker*:

> Still, the tale has a happy ending. Lehman Brothers eventually went belly up. A battle between the traders and the corporate financiers caused the firm to collapse in early 1984. The traders won, but what was left of the **august house** of Lehman wasn’t worth living in.  The senior partners were forced to go hat in hand to Wall Street rival Shearson, which bought them out.

I'm not sure what "august house" means in the sentence.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_House) has this explanation of "august house":

> "August House is an independent children's book publisher established in 1978 and currently headquartered in Atlanta, Georgia. August House principally focuses on publishing children's folktales, picture books, early-grade chapter books, and storytelling resource materials."

But that explanation of "august house" doesn't make sense in the context of the sentence written by Michael Lewis.

Can someone help me?

Comment: The publisher's name is obviously derivative. 'August' is an adjective here; you should look it up.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - sorry not sure what you mean by "publisher's name is obviously derivative".  August means admiration.  So is the author saying what was left of the inspiring Lehman wasn't worth staying for?

Comment: I'd imagine the Atlanta publisher is pronounced like the month, named for Augustus Caesar. _August_, with stress on the second syllable, is also an English adjective dreived from the Latin.

Comment: [august](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/august): marked by majestic dignity or grandeur.  Sometimes you've gotta look the words up individually, not as a phrase.

Comment: +1 again. Incidentally the last sentence looks all wrong to an olde-fashionede English speaker here - should be *to Wall Street rival**s** Shearson, **who** bought them out.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"August" in this context refers to the adjective, not the month or proper noun.

According to *Oxford Living Dictionaries*, ***[august](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/august)*** means "respected and impressive."

Answer (score 0):

Octavius Caesar bigged himself up by adopting the surname '[bigged up](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3DAugustus2),' (*[augeo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=augeo)* means increase, enlarge).

As a result emperors' wives were called 'Augusta,' and the month following Julius's new month added a day and was called 'August,' and many later Emperors added the surname. It is an honorary title like Majesty, the Honourable, His Highness, His Holiness.

The **august** House of Lehman is a wry use of the title.